# Certbot Amazon Linux error can't generate ssl cert

Tags: amazon-ec2, certbot, amazon-linux

I am trying to run certbot on an Amazon Linux EC2 instance to generate an ssl cert. I have turned off both nginx and apache to make port `80` available for `certbot` to bind to.

I am running certbot with the following command:

`./certbot-auto certonly --standalone -d mydomain.com`

It is producing the following error:

[image: Error]

All the DNS record have been configured correctly as well so I'm not sure why this error is happening.

How can I make `certbot` run correctly?

Answer (score 1):

I had to specify the correct `http-01-port`.

```
./certbot-auto certonly **--http-01-port 8080** -d domain.com -d www.domain.com
```